# Datatype date displaying incorrect format

Tags: jquery, jqxgrid, jqxwidgets

I am struggling to display a datetime field in the grid correctly. It is showing as year first '**2010-05-01 00:00:00**' and not day first '**01-05-2010 00:00:00**'. In mysql, it's a datetime field. I have tried various options that I sourced from the developer docs, but nothing seems to work. I have posted my code and would be grateful if someone could highlight my error. Thanks

jQWidgets v3.2.2 (2014-Mar-21)
[Developer site](http://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-documentation/documentation/jqxgrid/jquery-grid-getting-started.htm)

```
var source =
            {
                datatype: "json",
                datafields: [
                     { name: 'id', type: 'string'},
                     { name: 'date', type: 'date'},
                     { name: 'activity', type: 'string'},
                     { name: 'user', type: 'string'},
                     { name: 'item', type: 'string'}
                ],
                cache: false,
                id: 'id',
                url: 'temp/rtvData.php',           
                updaterow: function (rowid, rowdata, commit) {
                    // synchronize with the server - send update command
                    var data = "update=true&FirstName=" + rowdata.FirstName + "&LastName=" + rowdata.LastName + "&Title=" + rowdata.Title;
                    data = data + "&EmployeeID=" + rowid;

                    $.ajax({
                        dataType: 'json',
                        url: 'temp/rtvData.php',
                        type: 'POST',
                        data: data,
                        success: function (data, status, xhr) {
                            // update command is executed.
                            commit(true);
                        }
                    });     
                }
            };

            var dataAdapter = new $.jqx.dataAdapter(source);

            // initialize the input fields.
            /* $("#activity").jqxInput({width: 150, height: 23});
            $("#user").jqxInput({width: 150, height: 23});
            $("#item").jqxInput({width: 150, height: 23}); */

            var dataAdapter = new $.jqx.dataAdapter(source);
            var editrow = -1;

            // initialize jqxGrid
            $("#jqxgrid").jqxGrid(
            {
                width: 740,
                editable: true,
                sortable: true,
                filterable: true,
                columnsresize: true,
                columnsreorder: true,
                source: dataAdapter,
                pageable: true,
                autoheight: true,
                altrows: true,
                theme: 'custom',
                columns: [
                  { text: 'id', editable: false, datafield: 'id', width: 90 },
                  { text: 'date', editable: false, datafield: 'date', cellsformat: 'D', filtertype: 'date', filterable: true, width: 190},
                  { text: 'Activity', editable: false, datafield: 'activity', width: 100 },
                  { text: 'User', editable: false, datafield: 'user', width: 160 },
                  { text: 'Box', editable: false, datafield: 'item', width: 'auto' },
                  /* { text: 'Edit', datafield: 'Edit', width: 90, sortable: false, filterable: false, columntype: 'button', cellsrenderer: function () {
                     return "Edit";
                     }, buttonclick: function (row) {
                     // open the popup window when the user clicks a button.
                     editrow = row;
                     var offset = $("#jqxgrid").offset();
                     $("#popupWindow").jqxWindow({ position: { x: parseInt(offset.left) + 60, y: parseInt(offset.top) + 60 }, theme: 'custom' });

                     // get the clicked row's data and initialize the input fields.
                     var dataRecord = $("#jqxgrid").jqxGrid('getrowdata', editrow);
                     $("#firstName").val(dataRecord.FirstName);
                     $("#lastName").val(dataRecord.LastName);
                     $("#title").val(dataRecord.Title);

                     // show the popup window.
                     $("#popupWindow").jqxWindow('open');
                 }
                 } */
                ]
            });
```

rtvData.php

```
{
    // SELECT COMMAND
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die("SQL Error 1: " . mysql_error());
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
        $act[] = array(
            'id' => $row['id'],
            'date' => $row['date'],
            'activity' => $row['activity'],
            'user' => $row['user'],
            'item' => $row['item']
          );
    }

    echo json_encode($act);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Possibly it could be due to the localization. Please check this Guide:

Your code:

```
{ text: 'date', editable: false, datafield: 'date', cellsformat: 'D', filtertype: 'date', filterable: true, width: 190},
```

Default Localization Members

```
 patterns: {
// long date pattern
 D: "dddd, MMMM dd, yyyy",
...
```

http://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-documentation/documentation/jqxgrid/jquery-grid-localization.htm

Good Example:

http://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-demo/demos/jqxgrid/localization.htm?web

**/edit 2014-08-24**

**How I would approach the problem:**

1. The first thing I would make sure that the SQL query will return a
   correct date format.

   SELECT DATE_FORMAT(datecolumn, %Y.%m.%d) AS NewDate FROM exampletable;

I like to use the [ISO 8601 standard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) because there is no problem with it.
Some infos at MySQL [DATE_FORMAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format).

1. In the next step of course you have to change the source object.
2. Now make sure that the reference is set. *(customer Localization File)*

   `script type="text/javascript" src="localization.js">`

   http://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-demo/demos/jqxgrid/localization.js
3. Now only the grid has to be adapted. *(localization attribut)*

   `$("#jqxgrid").jqxGrid(
           {
               width: 740,
               source: dataAdapter,
               sortable: true,
               filterable: true,
               pageable: true,
               theme: 'custom',
               localization: getLocalization('de'),
               columns: [
                 { text: 'Datefield', datafield: 'date', columntype: 'NewDate',     filtertype: 'date', width: 210, cellsalign: 'right', cellsformat: 'd' }
              ]
              });`

Comment: Skaw Thanks for reply. I have looked at localization, but being fairly new to jqxwidegts (3 days), I am slightly confused as to how I would apply the patterns to my code I posted. Can you offer any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: See first post under change.